PowerShell Copy-Item not copying deep folders?
I am writing a script to copy items to a drive when I connect a specific drive. The script works, but it won't copy deep subfolders
Here is a sample of my code:
$folder = @(Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\public" -recurse -directory -filter "Projects")
$folder
$folder.FullName
Copy-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Destination "Z:\" -Recurse

I assume the code would get the Projects folder from within other folders located deep in C:\Users\public.
EX: The command will work for my Personal folder located C:\Users\public\document\WIP\Personal, but it won't work for C:\Users\public\document\WIP\Personal\Projects
The Projects folder isn't empty, so I assume it should be able to locate and copy the folder, but it isn't and I'm not sure why
I've attempted to find answers to this problem, but most answers point to using robocopy instead
Does anyone know why this script section isn't working? Will I need to switch from copy-item to robocopy?
Note: $folder and $folder.FullName are just there to test that Get-ChildItem works, which has worked every time I tested it, but copy-item isn't

$folder.FullName contains C:\Users\public\document\WIP\Personal\Projects ?

@SantiagoSquarzon yes

what if you try with $folder | Copy-Item -Force -Recurse -Destination Z:\

@SantiagoSquarzon This does seem to work, any idea why?

I'm not sure  I don't see something wrong in your code. Get-ChildItem C:\Users\public\document\WIP\Personal\Projects lists items right?

@SantiagoSquarzon Correct, and the .fullname lists the entire path, so I assumed it would be able to copy the file with no issue

Oh, I actually misread your last comment as "This doesn't seem to work" my bad! So if piping the $folder array worked there can be 2 options, one can be that piping uses -LiteralPath instead of -Path and for some reason the paths had wildcard characters (which doesn't seem to be the case) or because you're using -Force which "Indicates that this cmdlet copies items that can't otherwise be changed, such as copying over a read-only file or alias.". You can try -LiteralPath $folder.FullName without -Force to see if that works otherwise it works cause -Force

what's the result of $folder.FullName.GetType().ToString()? Because if it's a array that might explain it. Piping causes it to be unrolled implicitly, that's why it works.

A little tweak to your code and adding the -Force switch on the Copy-Item cmdlet eliminates the error reading 'Projects' folder already existing in the destination path.
$sourcePath = "C:\Users\public"
$DestinationPath = "Z:\"

Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Directory -Recurse -Filter "Projects" | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse -Force 
}

